# Upgrade to c++11 from c++

Tags: c++, c++11, migration, upgrade

I'm looking for resources on quickly getting a grasp of c++11 features. Searching on Google I did find a number of resources. However, I failed to find a resource which would help a programmer with prior C++ knowledge.
I don't want to start reading hundreds of pages on C++11 features that I already know from C++. The best thing I found was the Wikipedia article on C++11, but still it doesn't have many examples. There are also some good articles explaining a certain feature of C++ (e.g. [lambdas](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)). But I couldn't find something that had them all in one place.
Does anyone know any books, links, etc...?

Comment: Read C++ standard? Read [proposal papers](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) at, say, GCC C++11 support status? Read [books that are updated for C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: I'll check out proposal papers, but as for the books, I did check out some of them, like C++ Primer. It's 1000+ pages on c++ with no way of extracting c++11 features (at least I couldn't).

Comment: Re-read the standard and notice parts that you was not aware of? Won't hurt. It sounds like you are trying to learn without reading. There ain't no such thing as a free lunch!

Comment: As far as I know there aren't many in depth books on new C++11 features yet.  One is Anthony Williams' "C++: Concurrency in Action" (http://www.manning.com/williams/). But as you might guess from the title it's not intended to cover new C++11 features in general; it focuses on the threading additions.

Comment: In addition to books and specs, I *highly* recommend spending a few hours perusing [www.cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com). Specifically all the (C++11) noted features and the deprecate notes. That site is very well laid out and extremely informative (not surprising, since many of the SO high-rep members have made contributions to it).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71540/Explicating-the-new-C-standard-C-0x-and-its-implem

Answer (score 1):

You may start reading here: [Elements of Modern C++ Style](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) -- this article from Herb Sutter can be considered as targeted for C++ programmers who start using C++11.

Everything about C++11 at one page is here: [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) by Bjarne Stroustrup

Answer (score 1):

I think Bjarne Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ is exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://isocpp.org/get-started. It has most of the details anyone could give you here.
Of course, Prof. Stroustrup's homepage (http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) is also one of the best places to find what you are looking for.